# How do you query for the existence of something in at least 1 row of an array type in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following schema and want to retrieve all the rows in which at least 1 'af' field inside the 'dbsnpAnnots' field is less than 0.1

```
scala> randVarsDF.printSchema
root
|-- chr: string (nullable = true)
|-- pos: long (nullable = true)
|-- ref: string (nullable = true)
|-- alt: string (nullable = true)
|-- dbsnpAnnots: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- af: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- common: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- rsid: string (nullable = true)
```

I know how to do this using UDFs and the DataSet api but I would also like to be able to do it in SQL as well.

Here's what I do right now:

```
select count(*) from RANDVARS where dbsnpAnnots[0].af < 0.1 or dbsnpAnnots[1].af < 0.1 or dbsnpAnnots[2].af < 0.1
```

This only searches through the first 3 elements in the dbsnpAnnots array though. I would like to search through all elements as there can be more than 3.

I also tried

```
select count(*) from RANDVARS where dbsnpAnnots[*].af < 0.1
```

But that is not a valid Spark SQL query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explode that array. Since it is an array of struct, you can use `inline`

```
select count(1) 
from (
  select inline(dbsnpAnnots) from RANDVARS 
) p 
where p.af < 0.1
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)